# Node.jsにてrequestでGETした値を戻り値として返す関数を作成したい

Tags: node.js, api

APIで得た結果を元にAPIを叩く…といった作業を行いたいのですが、
requestモジュールを使用する際には、function内に続けて書く方法しかないのでしょうか。（矢印の位置）

```
request.get({
    uri: URL,
    headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json'},
    qs: {
        // GETのURLの後に付く
        // ?hoge=hugaの部分
    },
    json: true
}, function(err, req, data){
    console.log(data);　←
});
```

コード引用：https://qiita.com/yuta0801/items/ff7f314f45c4f8dc8a48
複数回APIを使った結果を使用してAPIを叩きたいため、できれば結果であるdata部分を外に出したいです。
result = request.get としてみましたが、リクエストの情報しか取得できませんでした。
ご享受お願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

コールバックの代わりに`Promise`を使う方法が[READMEで紹介されています。](https://github.com/request/request#promises--asyncawait)方法としてはラッパーライブラリを使う方法とNode.jsの`promisify`を使う方法の２パターン存在します。

例えば`request-promise-native`を使うと次のように書けます。

```
const request = require("request-promise-native");

(async function () {
    try {
        const data = await request.get("https://www.example.com");
        console.log(data);
    } catch (err) {
        // エラー処理
    }
})();
```